# Is there a way to know exactly when the last task in a queue will begin in a multithread app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, web-worker

I've this (math?) problem in a nodeJS app I'm building as a job interview project:

An instance of piscinaJS manages a pool of 3 worker threads.

At any time there could be 3 files (1 each thread) being elaborated by the workers and a bunch waiting in the queue. Every time a worker finishes with a file, takes the next one from the queue (FIFO style).
I always know how long it will take for each file to be elaborated because it's directly proportional to its size (1 s/MB).

Is there a way to calculate, at the moment of pushing another file to the queue, the exact time in seconds when a worker will be available to work on it?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: No because the nature of time in executing JavaScript is not constant. If you have control over the worker code: One approach you might consider would be to have the worker message the main thread on each invocation with a new file. If you know the count of the files in advance, the running count of executions would tell you when the last execution is occurring.

Comment: As a demonstration of what I mean about time inconsistency, you can go to any perf test site (jsben.ch for instance) - write any simple test and execute it over and over. You will witness the time inconsistency.

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest`s support [onprogress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequestEventTarget/onprogress)... that still won't tell you how long a process will take though. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

You can estimate the time it takes to complete work based off of an average from previously completed work.

1. Determine a start time for processing (start)
2. Process some tasks, on completion increment (processed)
3. Determine the current rate by getting the average from (now)

   const now = new Date();
   const time = start - now;
   const average = time / processed
   const readyForNext = new Date(now + average)